# Show each side are a subset of each other

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that A ∪ (B − A) = A ∪ B by showing each side is a subset of the
other side.

= A ∪ (B ∩ A c ) set difference

= A ∪ (A c ∩ B) commutative

= (A ∪ A c ) ∩ (A ∪ B) distributive

= U ∩ (A ∪ B) complement

= A ∪ B identity

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: You've not done this using the method that they requested. The "showing each side is a subset of the other side method" involves picking an element from one side, and showing that it belongs to the other side. That is, use the fact that $x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B \iff A \subseteq B$

Comment: Could do you show me how to start it?

Comment: Sure! Please see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment, in order to prove $A \cup (B - A) = A \cup B$ using the method they requested, we need to pick an element from one side, show that it's in the other side, and then do the same going back from the right to the left side. I encourage you to ponder/prove why $x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B$ means the same thing as $A \subseteq B$.

To demonstrate, to prove $A \cup (B - A) \subseteq A \cup B$, we need to show $x \in A \cup (B - A) \Rightarrow x \in A \cup B$. Recall that to prove a "$p \Rightarrow q$" statement, you suppose $p$ and then show $q$. In that regard, suppose that $x \in A \cup (B - A)$. Then $x \in A$ or $x \in (B - A)$. If $x \in A$, then $x \in A \cup B$ and we are done. If $x \in (B - A)$, then $x \in B \Rightarrow x \in A \cup B$. Either way, we have that $x \in A \cup B$ so that $A \cup (B - A) \subseteq A \cup B$.

For the converse, we need to pick some $x \in A \cup B$ and show that $x \in A \cup (B - A)$. I'll leave this one to you, but once you've done that you'll have shown that $A \cup B \subseteq A \cup (B - A)$. Then since you've shown $A \cup (B - A) \subseteq A \cup B$ and $A \cup (B - A) \subseteq A \cup B$ (i.e., that each side is a subset of the other), you can conclude that $A \cup (B - A) = A \cup B$.

This might seem like a very unintuitive way to prove set equalities at first (indeed your method was much shorter), but it pays off in that this is a go-to method to prove harder set equalities, so it's good to practice it now.

Comment: Thats great! Could we also prove it by the membership table?

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard of a membership table... A quick Google search tells me that it's probably entirely up to the instructor (and definitely valid as far as "proofs" go). What I can tell you is that you won't see it used very often in mathematics, so imo it's worthwhile to know how to at least read and understand a proof like that ^

Comment: oh okay i'll stick with this method.   So would this be a proper reason then ,  Let x ∈ A ∪ (B − A). Then x ∈ A or x ∈ (B − A) by definition of union. So x ∈ B and x is not subset of A (by set difference). But x ∈ A by previous statement, so x ∈ A or x ∈ B. By definition of union, x ∈ (A ∪ B).

Comment: Good choice if you're planning to do more mathematics! Definitely check with your instructor for their opinion though :) As far as your method goes, your first step was perfect. But how did you arrive at "$x \in B$ and ... "? Whenever you have an "or", you need to consider each case separately (i.e., if option 1 then... if not option 1, then option 2, hence... )

Comment: I used the by set difference definition for arriving at that stage. I am not to sure what method the instructor requires which is why I came up with this.

Comment: What I mean is that from $x \in A$ or $x \in (B - A)$, you need to do something like: either $x \in A$ or $x \notin A$. If $x \in A$, then $x \in A \cup B$. On the other hand, if $x \notin A$, then $x \in (B - A)$, which implies $x \in B$, and hence $x \in A \cup B$.

Comment: But then how would you write the reasoning? I think the teacher was looking for a reason rather than just explaining the step

Comment: That ^^^ for me is the reasoning. If you really wanted to, you could include things like if $x \in A$, then $x \in A \cup B$ since the union of a set with another set doesn't remove any elements.. But imo that's too much detail. Again, check with them what level of detail is appropriate.